# Project build error: 'groupId' with value 'IOCProj1(Basic)' does not match a valid id pattern

Tags: maven

I have an issue with my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>IOCProj1(Basic)</groupId>
  <artifactId>IOCProj1(Basic)</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Stack: This is the error showing in console

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'groupId' with value 'IOCProj1(Basic)' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 3, column 12
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project IOCProj1(Basic):com.nt.cfgs:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\shrut\workspace\IOCProj1(Basic)\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'groupId' with value 'IOCProj1(Basic)' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 3, column 12
[ERROR] 
`enter code here`[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use parentheses inside a `groupId` or `artifactId`.

These fields are validated by the following regular expression: [`[A-Za-z0-9_\\-.]+`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/validation/DefaultModelValidator.java#L67) in Maven. Hence, you cannot have parentheses; the only valid characters are alphanumeric, underscore, dash and dot. You could rename your project to:

```
<groupId>IOCProj1_Basic</groupId>
<artifactId>IOCProj1_Basic</artifactId>
```

Comment: faster than light, as usual

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Looks like it isn't documented though... I can't find it unless looking the code.

Comment: that's what I actually was wondering: where did he get the information from! Well done by digging into the code. Big kudos

Answer (score 3):

According DefaultModelValidator class 'artifactId' and 'groupId' have to match following regular expression

ID_REGEX = "[A-Za-z0-9_\-.]+"
If you are intrested in other validations of maven pom file, looking into this class source code will be helpful.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/maven-2/branches/maven-2.2.x/maven-project/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/project/validation/DefaultModelValidator.java

Comment: its just for document help, I am appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

--- while creating application should not  give space  and moreover project name and artifact id should be same