# Use Maven dependency with special characters in artifactId

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency, jitpack

I want to add a Maven dependency that's hosted on the [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/) repository. The `artifactId` contains dots and, therefore, cannot be downloaded due to [issues within JitPack's infrastructure](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/1145).

The workaround is to replace `.` with `~`. But [Maven forbids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631066/1809463) the use of this kind of special character in valid patterns for `artifactId`.

It works in Gradle, though.

```
group 'org.example.project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.iotaledger:iota~lib~java:0.9.10'
}
```

Is there any workaround that allows me to use this library with Maven? E.g. downloading it to the local repository and changing its name, etc.?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602256/1809463) describes a solution with a local repo and `mvn deploy:deploy-file` but unfortunately there are manual steps necessary for every user.